# Qt 5.7 drawRect with big stroke width drawing cut out corners

Tags: qt, qpainter

I am trying to draw a rectangle with big stroke width(set by a QPen) and QPainter is drawing the rectangle but all of the corners are a little cut out, not as sharp as they ought to be. Here is an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/omAdY.png

I'm drawing it on top of a QWidget using this code:

```
m_painter.drawRect(upLeftX, upLeftY, downRightX - upLeftX, downRightY - upLeftY);
```

Comment: Take a look at [`QPen::setJoinStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpen.html#setJoinStyle).  You need `Qt::MiterJoin`.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why they thought this to be the default behaviour. You can submit an answer if you want so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved from comment.

You can set the pen's join style easily using [`QPen::setJoinStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpen.html#setJoinStyle).  To modify the pen currently in use by the `QPainter` use something like...

```
QPen pen = m_painter.pen();
pen.setJoinStyle(Qt::MiterJoin);
m_painter.setPen(pen);
```